# Accessing Google Drive API using service account

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to access Google Drive API using a service account. I had set up the service account to access Google Directory API and I assume I can use the same for this. Here is my code, it's pretty much self-explanatory.

```java
     private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = service.files().list();

        do {
            FileList files = request.execute();

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
                 request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
         return result;
      }

    public static Drive getDriveService(){
        GoogleDriectoryService GDservice = new GoogleDriectoryService();
        java.io.File serviceAccountP12Certificate = GDservice.loadF("resources/APIProject-62d885cdf671.p12");
         HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();//?
         JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();//?
         GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setTransport(httpTransport)
          .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
          .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmailAddress)
          .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
          .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(serviceAccountP12Certificate)
          .build();
          Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
              .setApplicationName("radiantlogic-vds").build();
         return service;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Drive service = getDriveService();
            List<File> files = retrieveAllFiles(service);
            System.out.println(files);
    }
```

But, I'm getting "com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized" at `request.execute()` line. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try checking if you had a successful login credentials? You can try following [Instantiate a Drive service object](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) code sample to help you do the authorization to make API requests. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I am doing the exact same thing to instantiate a Drive service and it seems to be working fine. But it fails on `execute()` I don't know why.

Comment: thanks @Mr.Rebot for the link. I found out the reason for the issue. I had forgotten to authorize the service account with right scope.